# Create a "open in XYZ app" link for iOS App companion site

Tags: javascript, html

In Yelp mobile page, there is a link will open App store if the app has not been installed.

```
<a data-fallback-url="itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/yelp/id284910350" href="yelp:///">Open in the Yelp App</a>
```

I think the `data-fallback-url` and some javascript did the magic, can somebody give any hint how this happened?